# i am not able to add instagram embed in my react js

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import InstagramEmbed from 'react-instagram-embed';
export function Embed() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Embed</h2>
            <InstagramEmbed
            url='https://instagr.am/p/Zw9o4/'
            clientAccessToken='123|456'
            maxWidth={320}
            hideCaption={false}
            containerTagName='div'
            protocol=''
            injectScript
            onLoading={() => {}}
            onSuccess={() => {}}
            onAfterRender={() => {}}
            onFailure={() => {}}
           />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried hard but i could not add instagram embed in my react app

Comment: your `clientAccessToken` is invalid it seems..  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/#access-tokens

Comment: Hi Raaz, please add more detail explaining what errors you're receiving or what's not working for you.

Comment: I had error in my console "GET https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/instagram oembed/? Hidecaption bla bla bla     400"